# How to save database connection easy and safe?

Tags: 7, database, security

I'm trying to let Drupal7 connect to several databases(pgsql) and update data automatically. So I use `Database::addConnectionInfo($name,'default',$connString)` And `db_set_active($name)`.

It works perfectly until I realize it's dangerous to save database password in fields while the connection string actually needs it.

Is there any way to do so easy and safe?

Thank you! :)

Comment: You may have better luck on http://security.stackexchange.com/ - here we can talk implementation, but to know *what* to implement, they are just the guys. Long story short, you will need to keep all the data Drupal needs to know full text password in files or database, so if someone will break into your Drupal, all your databases should be considered compromised anyway.

Comment: Pgsql support several kinds of connection such as trust and public key. But I'm not sure which way drupal7 also support, excepts put password in connection string directly. I will take a look that site, thank you!

Comment: If you'll give Drupal key to database, it is about as bad as giving it password. I mean, if someone is up there stealing your data, you are only moving what he needs to steal from database entry to another kind of database entry, or file (depends on where you want to store keys). I guess I could investigate how to hack in key support into Drupal, but I can't see a point of doing it.

Comment: Are you storing the password? If so: How are you storing the password? Do you use https on the site? Can you encrypt the field?

Comment: @greggles but if he will encrypt the field, he will need to keep data needed to decrypt it in a place avaliable to Drupal, too. So this will make stealing pass only a bit less convenient, not in any way really harder.

Comment: @greggles encrypt field is what I want to do, until I find a module says you should not encrypt because it's NOT truly safe, just a trick. So I'm trying to find another way. Guys both hit the point, I think if we have to store password in field, a module provide Encrypt/Decrypt API and hard-coded key/salt is a better choice, isn't it? In this case, even my drupal database has been hacked, password is still safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is the [encrypt module](https://drupal.org/project/encrypt) which can encrypt your data. Be sure to use the 7.x-2.x branch.

And yes, store the key somewhere on the filesystem that is not easily accessed and it should be hard for an attacker who has db access to be able to decrypt the info.

Just be sure that there's no way to execute php via the Drupal interface. A module like [paranoia](https://drupal.org/project/paranoia) can help in that.

Comment: Great! Especially it can use key outside the web root. Thank you!